# Firebase Auth password wrong after signing in with email link

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an Angular app and using Firebase E-mail Authentication.
This worked perfectly, until I started using the confirm account e-mail link.

Upon signing up, I create the user and then send them a sign in link to their mail.
I tried this, I signed up, got a link, clicked on it, and it signed in all right.

However, once I sign out, it doesn't give let me sign in with my password, saying `The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.`
I need to reset the password and only then it works.

This is my code:

```
signup(email: string, password: string, firstname: string, lastname, nickname: string, address: string) {
this.firebaseAuth
  .auth
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(value => {
    this.u = value.user;
    this.u.updateProfile({ displayName: nickname, photoURL: null });
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.updateCurrentUser(this.u);
    var actionCodeSettings = {
      // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
      // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
      //url: 'http://localhost:4200/finishSignUp',
      url: 'https://mybay-990af.firebaseapp.com/finishSignUp',
      // This must be true.
      handleCodeInApp: true,
    };

    this.firebaseAuth.auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(function () {
        // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
        // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
        // if they open the link on the same device.
        window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
      });
    console.log('Success!', value);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
  });
 }

loginWithEmailLink() {
// Confirm the link is a sign-in with email link.
if (this.firebaseAuth
  .auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
  // Additional state parameters can also be passed via URL.
  // This can be used to continue the user's intended action before triggering
  // the sign-in operation.
  // Get the email if available. This should be available if the user completes
  // the flow on the same device where they started it.

  var email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
  if (!email) {
    // User opened the link on a different device. To prevent session fixation
    // attacks, ask the user to provide the associated email again. For example:
    email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
  }
  // The client SDK will parse the code from the link for you.
  this.firebaseAuth
    .auth.signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)
    .then((result) => {
      // Clear email from storage.
      window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
      // You can access the new user via result.user
      // Additional user info profile not available via:
      // result.additionalUserInfo.profile == null
      // You can check if the user is new or existing:
      // result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
      this.u = result.user;
      this.sendPaymentMethod(email).then(sent => {
        this.router.navigate(['/store'])
      });

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
      // Common errors could be invalid email and invalid or expired OTPs.
    });
}
}

login(email: string, password: string) {
var signed = this.firebaseAuth
  .auth
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(value => {

    return true;

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return err.message;
  });

return signed;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are confused with email link authentication and confirmation of email address. Both methods send email to your user. In first case you will send a link to your user to log in to your app, think about it as sign in with Google or Facebook, you have no password in this scenario, but instead of sending request to those providers you will send a fresh email every time.
For second case(you try to make this one) you need to create user with email password combination(what you've already done it but instead of sending verification email you send link for email sign in). In action settings set continue url back to your app. And finally when you are back apply oob code(you got it as url parameter).

I modified your code so you'll have an example what to do:

```
signup(email: string, password: string, firstname: string, lastname, 
    nickname: string, address: string) {
 this.firebaseAuth
  .auth
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(value => {
    this.u = value.user;
    this.u.updateProfile({ displayName: nickname, photoURL: null });
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.updateCurrentUser(this.u);
    var actionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'https://www.example.com/?email=' + this.u.email,
      handleCodeInApp: true,
    };
    this.u.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings);

    console.log('Success!', value);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
  });
 }

emailVerfication() {
  this.firebaseAuth.auth.applyActionCode(this.route.snapshot.queryParams.oobCode)
     .then(() => console.log('BINGO!'));
}
```

Sign in with email/password, email verification docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#passing_statecontinue_url_in_email_actions

Comment: Great! Thanks! Although ```applyActionCode``` is unnecessary, since the default Firebase link from the email verifies the account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the out of band or oobCode and then prompt user to enter a password. Finally, you pass that to `.confirmPasswordReset`.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function () {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
})

function verifyPassword(oobCode, newPassword, email) {
    firebase.auth().confirmPasswordReset(oobCode, newPassword).then(function (resp) {
        // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.
        // TODO: Display a link back to the app, or sign-in the user directly
        // if the page belongs to the same domain as the app:
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, newPassword);
        toast('Password Changed');
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Error occurred during confirmation. The code might have expired or the
        // password is too weak.
        toast(error.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I get this oobCode?
Does this mean that a password reset has to be done always after verifying the email?

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior that the account can not be signed in with password. When a user signs in with an email link, there is no password associated with the user account. And this is the main benefit of email link login - users do not need to generate or remember one more password.

For these password-less user accounts, the chance of account being hijacked is reduced since there is no possibility of reusing password or creating simple passwords.

Comment: But how does he sign in the second time? Does he need to always click the link? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: Yeah the user will need to send the link and click it the next time the user needs to sign in on another device. If you are just using email link sign in as a "invite" mechanism, then you should ask the user to set a password after they click the link and complete sign-in.